# Why is entropy in information theory not always increasing?

Tags: markov-chains, information-theory, entropy

I am reading "Elements of Information Theory" by Cover and and I can't understand one paragraph, specifically the highlighted part:

> "One of the basic laws of physics, the second law of thermodynamics,
> states that the entropy of an isolated system is nondecreasing. We now
> explore the relationship between the second law and the entropy function
> that we defined earlier in this chapter.
> In statistical thermodynamics, entropy is often defined as the log of
> the number of microstates in the system. This corresponds exactly to our
> notion of entropy if all the states are equally likely. But why does entropy
> increase?
> We model the isolated system as a Markov chain with transitions obeying the physical laws governing the system. Implicit in this assumption is
> the notion of an overall state of the system and the fact that knowing the
> present state, the future of the system is independent of the past. In such
> a system we can find four different interpretations of the second law. **It
> may come as a shock to find that the entropy does not always increase.**
> However, relative entropy always decreases."

How do I understand that? I know that entropy from theormodynamics and from information theory are related, but are not the same thing, but does it mean that the entropy from information theory doesn't obey the second law of thermodynamics?

Comment: Maybe you can have e.g. Markov chains where everything will end at node 0 given long enough time, my intuition would be that entropy doesn't increase here?  Iirc entropy always increases when every edge is symmetric, i.e. probability to go from $i$ to $j$ equals probability to go from $j$ to $i$, and they are all non-zero.

Comment: This is not possible to answer without more context. Cover has a 2 page discussion following your quoted fragment discussing *exactly why* he makes the statement that confused you. Please edit the question adding details and pinpointing what you don't understand about his explanation.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75146/entropy-and-information

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. @kodlu I edited the question and filled all the previous context that was given in the book. I think further author gives example of Markov chain that has entropy decreasing (MC that starts from uniform distribution has maximum entropy so it can only decrease with time), but he doesn't really explain what it means and how it relates to second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: Should I just assume that the entropy from information theory is different than the entropy from thermodynamics and the second law simply doesn't hold for it?

Comment: Thanks @leonbloy, I will read through this thread, it seems to be about same thing.